# why am i getting different answers for the following

Tags: javascript

I am getting different outputs for the following code. please tell me the difference

```
        var y = 1;
        var c = "anything";
        var d = 5;
        console.log(y == 1 && "anything"); // Output is anything
        console.log( "anything" && y == 1 ); // Output is true
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: `&&` operator would return last truthy value or false. Since `"anything"` is true, first expression would return `"anything"`. In second expression, `y==1` will be first evaluated, resulting in `true` and hence it is returned

Comment: You get different outputs because you're performing different operations.  The "difference" is the order in which you perform the operations.

Comment: @deceze: Perhaps there's a duplicate somewhere, but *that* question's answers don't answer this question.

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/208/comparison-operations/1587/short-circuiting-in-boolean-operators#t=201704031204287011226

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` and `||` are *surprisingly powerful* in JavaScript as compared to some other languages: They don't necessarily return a boolean.

`&&` evaluates its first operand and, if that's falsy*, uses that as its return value; if the first operand evalutes truthy*, `&&` evaluates its second operand and uses that as its result value. In your `y == 1 && "anything"`, since `y == 1` is `true` (which is, of course, truthy), the result is the result of evaluating `"anything"` (which is `"anything"`). In your `"anything" && y == 1`, `"anything"` is truthy, and so the result is  the result of evaluating `y == 1` (which is `true`).

`||` works in a similar manner: It evaluates its first operand and, if that's truthy, uses that as its result value; otherwise, `||` evaluates its second operand uses uses that as its result value.

---

* falsy and truthy:

falsy - A value that coerces to `false` when used as a boolean. The falsy values are: `""`, `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`. *(On browsers, `document.all` is also falsy, for complicated reasons. If you're really curious, I cover it in Chapter 17 of my book* JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.)*

truthy - A value that coerces to `true` when used as a boolean. Any non-falsy value is truthy, incl. `"0"` (zero in quotes), `"false"` (false in quotes), empty functions, empty arrays, and empty objects.

Comment: You can also tag docs: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/208/comparison-operations/1587/short-circuiting-in-boolean-operators#t=201704031204287011226